# How to force Calcite NOT to optimise SQL query while executing RelNode?

Tags: apache-calcite

I'm building and executing RelNodes, and have only one jdbc source connected to Calcite.
Sometimes Calcite ignores what is said in the RelNode and can simply push down "SELECT *" even if the node contains aggregation or column rename. As far as I understand it happens because Calcite has optimisation engine and this engine sometimes decides that it will be easier just to get whole records and process them in my app.

Does anybody know how to turn off this engine or how to configure it in a way to prevent such optimisations?

Code example:

```java
        Class.forName(CALCITE_JDBC_DRIVER);
        Properties info = new Properties();
        info.setProperty("lex", "JAVA");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:", info);
        calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);

        rootSchema = calciteConnection.getRootSchema();
        rootSchema.add("foo", JdbcSchema...);

        frameworkConfig = Frameworks.newConfigBuilder()
                .parserConfig(SqlParser.Config.DEFAULT)
                .defaultSchema(rootSchema)
                .programs()
                .traitDefs(ConventionTraitDef.INSTANCE, RelDistributionTraitDef.INSTANCE)
                .operatorTable(SqlOperatorTables.chain(
                        TrinoSqlOperatorTable.INSTANCE,
                        SqlStdOperatorTable.instance()))
                .build();

        relRunner = calciteConnection.unwrap(RelRunner.class);

        RelBuilder relBuilder = RelBuilder.create(frameworkConfig);
        var relNode = relBuilder
                .scan("foo", "bar", "table")
                .rename(relBuilder.peek().getRowType().getFieldNames().stream()
                        .map(f -> f + "_postfix")
                        .toList())
                .sort(relBuilder.field(1))
                .aggregate(relBuilder.groupKey(2),
                        relBuilder.sum(relBuilder.field(3)))
                .build();
        relRunner.prepareStatement(relNode).executeQuery();
```

When I execute this code Calcite pushes down very naive request to the foo source:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  "bar"."table"
```

I want Calcite to push down exactly what I have in the rel node. Any ideas how to avoid this optimisation?

Comment: Can you show your code? It's hard to suggest what to change without knowing what you have.

Comment: Added a code example. Pls let me know if you will need more details. Hope it's more clear now)

Comment: Calcite can't just push down exactly what you have without rules to do so. It needs to know that it is possible for the data source to execute such a query. This is not likely a case of Calcite optimizing your query to avoid pushing things down, but rather Calcite not knowing how to push your predicates down because it hasn't been told. What is the data source you are using?

Comment: In my example 'foo' is a JdbcSchema connected to postgress. Quite often it works fine and pushes down everything correctly. I definitely know it can pushes donw aggregation and ordering to my pg. Thing is that sometimes it just ignores rel node, do "select *" and apply rel's stuff in my app instead of doing it in the db. I want somehow to force Calcite to do maximum pushdown all the time. At least for jdbc connections)